# How to send key events to webkit.WebView() control?

Tags: python, keyboard, gtk

I created mini browser for touch panels. I used Python, GTK and WebKit. I want to create touch keyboard built-in that browser. How to send key events to webkit.WebView() control?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import webkit, gtk
window = gtk.Window()
browser = webkit.WebView()
window.add(browser)
window.show()
browser.show()
browser.load_uri("http://google.com")
window.fullscreen()
window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
window.set_title("Dashboard")
gtk.main()
```

Sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
event = gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS)
event.keyval = gtk.keysyms.Return
event.time = 0
browser.emit('key-press-event', event)
```

for example, to send an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript in the code, there is a good example of communicating with webkit on this page:

http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

Read trough it all to understand his logic. Essentially he uses a simple javascript to send data back via titlechange in the browser.